# How to fix 'JSON parsging error: continue (at offeset XXXX)' error from ogr2ogr

Tags: postgis, geojson, ogr2ogr

I have a 25 GB GeoJSON I want to convert into 10x10 degree rasters (tifs) covering most of the land on earth, with the rasters' values a particular field in the GeoJSON. My plan was to convert the GeoJSON into a PostGIS table using ogr2ogr, then convert the PostGIS table into 10x10 degree tiles. However, I'm getting an error during importation into PostGIS.

The GeoJSON's type is "FeatureCollection" and its name is "sql_statement". I can successfully import GeoJSONs with a few small features into PostGIS, so I know ogr2ogr is working properly.

I am trying: `ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"dbname=ubuntu" "final_plantations.geojson" -nln plantations -progress`

I expected it to import but received the following error:

`ERROR 1: JSON parsing error: continue (at offset 1183876445)
ERROR 4: Failed to read GeoJSON data
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource 'final_plantations.geojson' with the following drivers.
  -> 'PCIDSK'
  -> 'netCDF'
  -> 'JP2OpenJPEG'`

etc.

I assume this means there's a problem with a particular feature or that the GeoJSON is too large to import but I'm not sure. Please help me with importing this GeoJSON. Alternatively, if you have ideas about how to directly rasterize the GeoJSON, that'd be great, too. I tried using `gdal_rasterize` but received the same error as above, minus the failure to find a driver.